# What is meant by a "Name" in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel), it says that the `Application.Evaluate` method takes a single parameter, which is called a `Name` and is of `Variant` datatype. The description of what `Name` means in this context is:

> A formula or the name of the object, using the **naming convention of Microsoft Excel**. The length of the name must be less than or equal to 255 characters.

**emphasis my own*

What exactly is meant by the Excel naming convention? What rules govern it and where are these documented?

In the **Remarks** section of the article, there are some examples of possible types of `Name` that can be used - but one type of that can be used in the method is

> Defined names. You can specify any name in the language of the macro.

Which begs the question; what is a *"name in the language of the macro"* defined as?

Or to tie this more closely to the specific programming question I'm trying to solve; what can `blah` be in `Application.Evaluate(blah)` for the function to evaluate correctly?

Comment: The example provided in your link under remarks shows clearly what kind of arguments can be used for this methode to work correctly. I don't understand where the confusion may be.

Comment: @sgdva Yes, perhaps I was not clear in the question, but in that **Remarks** section it has the line "*Defined names. You can specify any name in the language of the macro.*" - That's what's confusing me (and what I assume the "naming convention" referred to in the extract I quoted is talking about - some mysterious "language of the macro"). Perhaps *pnuts*' link will shed some light however, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Check the answer below, I found it very useful for this matter and I think it's pretty clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Excel, a `Name` (in the context of ranges) can mean a few things:

**A Defined Name**

For example, if you select cell "A1" and in the top left corner of the screen change "A1" to `"MyCellName"` you now have a `Named Range`. This allows you to reference `"MyCellName"` instead of `"A1"` in formulas. This is particularly useful with constant input ranges, or when defining a name for a larger range.

**Named Ranges Can Overlap**

Say, for example's sake, you now highlight `"A1-B3"` and change the `Name` to `"MyNamedRange"`. You, just as before, can use this name in formulas. You can still refer to `"MyCellName"` as well to refer to `"A1"`, despite it being within `"MyNamedRange"`.

**Automatic Names**

Ever created a `Table` or `PivotTable`? These, in essence, become names as well. They can be referred to by their names. For example, if you create a table, the default name is `Table1`. In a formula, you can refer to the entire table using `Table1` (super useful with VLOOKUPS).

**Default Names**

The most common *Names* are plain ranges. `"A1"` is a name that points to the cell `"A1"`. Same for every other cell. Even cells that have defined names can still be referred to by their range reference.

**For Purposes of the Article**

All the article is saying is that you can refer to a range using the standard methods of referring to a range. If I do `Application.Evaluate "MyNamedCell"` it will evaluate `"A1"` and if I do `Application.Evaluate "A1"` it will again evaluate `"A1"`.

For evaluating variables, what is actually happening is `Application.Evaluate` is first resolving the range reference (figuring out what you mean by the parameter passed) and it is then operating on that object. As long as you are passing a valid `Range` reference that can be evaluated, it will evaluate it. This means you can put a bunch of range references into an array of arrays within a class that is the property of... see where I am going with this? <del>Use whatever you want, but in the end it needs to know where the range is.</del>

**EDIT:** Regarding your updated edit of 'What can the name be?', you need some string that can be passed in and evaluated. Pretty straightforward.

```
Dim SomeFoo as Range
Set SomeFoo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range

' Isnt what we need since evaluate wants a string
' NOTE: This will implicitly take the .Value property of SomeFoo and
' try to evaluate that. This is fine, but bad coding practice (assuming SomeFoo's value is the address)
Application.Evaluate(SomeFoo).Value = "SomeString"

' The address can be successfully evaluated as a string
Application.Evaluate(SomeFoo.Address).Value = "SomeString"

' If SomeFoo contains an address/name it can be successfully evaluated
Application.Evaluate(SomeFoo.Value).Value = "SomeString"
```

Comment: Also: a names doesn't need to point to a Range, it can refer to a constant value such as "10" or "whatever"

Comment: ^ Learned something new :).